# No pos tags by Spacy's multilingual xx_ent_wiki_sm

Tags: spacy, pos-tagger

I am using Spacy's multilingual pos-tagger -- xx_ent_wiki_sm. The problem is it doesn't return any pos tags. If you have encountered the same issue, please, share your ideas/solution. Thank you!

Code in python:

````
nlp = spacy.load('xx_ent_wiki_sm')
doc = nlp(u'Por David García')
print(' '.join('{word}/{tag}'.format(word=t.orth_, tag=t.pos_) for t in doc))

Por/ David/ García/```
````

Answer (score 1):

This model does not contain a part-of-speech tagger, it only contains a named entity recognizer.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! Could you recommend a multi-language pos-tagger? A single model that would work for a bunch of languages?